# How to know when a handlebars template has finished rendering/rerendering

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template to display a table.

The content changes on a drop down select which makes an ajax call to get data for the  template. Now I need to add a CSS class to a table row dynamically after the data gets fetched. Now I have to add a timeout of 100 ms so the selector works.

Because at the point I am setting the class the first time the table tr does not exist. How do I know if the handlebars template is done rendering the new data ( first time ) so I do not have to rely on timeOut function. This is the controller function that sets data for the template and add CSS.

```
    updateData: function(data,index)
    {
        this.set('data',data);

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('sleep');
            Ember.$('.table tr').removeClass("active");
            Ember.$('.table tr:eq(' + (index+1) + ')').addClass("active");
        }, 100);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of problem that is best solved using an `Ember.View`, it will make things easier.

You can create a view for each row in your table and in each view you can use the `classNameBindings` property that will add or remove any number of CSS classes according to the property they are bound to.

See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html

In your template you would have something like:

```
<table>
  {{#each item in model}}
    {{view 'my-row' ...}}
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

And in your view you would have something like:

```
Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    classNameBindings: ['active']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Ember.run.scheduleOnce` method to schedule the CSS class manipulation to occur after the `afterRender` queue is emptied (i.e. the dom is fully rendered)

[Click here for more information about the Ember Run Loop](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/)

So in your example,

```
updateData: function(data,index) {
    this.set('data',data);

    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
        console.log('sleep');
        Ember.$('.table tr').removeClass("active");
        Ember.$('.table tr:eq(' + (index+1) + ')').addClass("active");
    });

}
```